# how to access angularjs variable in other html page java script

Tags: angularjs

how to access angularjs variable from controler to other html page java script

```
controller
 $scope.names = [
                      {name:'Jani'} ,
              {name:'raaj'} 
                      ];
               $scope.number = names.length;
```

i need to display use number in html page JavaScript please help in how to use it

Comment: Please take a few more moments to word your question. Do you want to show it in the view? On another website? In case of the former: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Comment: i want to use "number" variable in html page JavaScript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getAngularValue(){
 var number = {};
 number = angular.element(document.getElementById("YOUR_ANGULAR_PAGE_ID")).scope().number;
}
```

Comment: <html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script >
function getAngularValue(){
alert("getAngularValue");
 var  number = angular.element(document.getElementById("namesCtrl")).scope().names;
alert("hi");
}
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
{{names }}
</ul>
<button onclick="getAngularValue()">Click me</button>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names =  "test";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
it is not working