# Call Angular controller function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some Angular 1.4 code I've inherited, which has some bizarre scope issues I'm trying to tidy up - and I'm stuck on a particular one.

I have an ES6 Class controller (Babelified) - in it, I have a method like this

```
save(data) {
    this.validate(data);
    .... do some more stuff
}
```

I also have a View and model and html and all that good stuff. In it I have a custom directive for radio buttons - like this

```
<radio onupdate="vm.save" data="model.myradio1" />
```

My Radio directive seems to have two bindings for onupdate & data

```
.directive('radio', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'radio',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            onupdate: '='
        }
    };
})
```

the template contains

```
ng-click="radio.onupdate($parent.data);" <-- This looks suspect but no idea what it does!
```

However - this then explodes in ways I wouldn't have expected:

```
this.validate is not a function
```

I can see how this happened - `this` now refers to the radio buttons scope. But how do I fix it? I'm pretty new to Angular.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854586/how-to-access-angularjs-variable-in-other-html-page-java-script/35857536#35857536 . see the answer in this post. access function instead of variable.

Comment: Post directive code: its `scope` configuration and how `onupdate` is called from inside.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me rebind `this` to my controller rather than the directive scope?

Comment: Once again, post necessary information, your post missing the most important parts I highlighted.

Comment: Sorry - that was a response to the person before you - post updated with the directive definition and an excerpt from the template

Comment: Why `radio.onupdate` and not `onupdate` are you using controllerAs in directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke a controller method from the directive you need to create a "reference" function with `&` scope configuration:

```
.directive('radio', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'radio',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            onupdate: '&'
        }
    };
})
```

Then from directive template you need to call it like this:

```
ng-click="onupdate({data: $parent.data});"
```

And finally the usage of the radio directive becomes:

```
<radio onupdate="vm.save(data)" data="model.myradio1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I stick to your **question title** '*how to call controller function from directive*'.

I've made an example that uses a `<select>` element and calls the controller function `$scope.filterHall()` to send the selected object, whenever the user changes value.

**Directive** (i get the changeHall function and i call it into the template,see below ):

```
.directive('eventHallsList', function($timeout, $log, $http, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        changeHall: '&',
        items: '=',
        model: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'mytemplate.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }

    }
  });
```

**Template:** **Into the select element everytime the user selects a value, i call the `changeHall()` which is bind to the controller's function `$scope.filterHall()` , and it pass the object.**

```
<select style="color:#337ab7"
        ng-change="changeHall({value:model})" ng-model="model"
        ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
    <option value=""> choose hall</option>
</select>
```

live example : http://plnkr.co/edit/iCS0blQjceA4tIIb8bUV?p=preview

Hope helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem, when you use HTML element on*** attribute to register listeners. You have to bind controller context to listener function.

```
<radio onupdate="vm.save.bind(vm)" data="model.myradio1" />
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: You can't use `bind` in Angular expression. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecff